# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; about ExtractValue

Tags: mysql

The code I am using is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'data/medline17n0001.xml' 
INTO TABLE journal

LINES STARTING BY '<PubmedArticle>' TERMINATED BY '</PubmedArticle>'
(@tmp)

SET
Title = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//Title'),  
ISOAbbreviation = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//ISOAbbreviation'),
ISSN = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//ISSN'), 
PubDate = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//PubDate/Year'),
Volume = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//Volume');
```

However, it always gives back the error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'Title = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//Title'),
> ISOAbbreviation = ExtractValue(@tmp,' at line 8

Can anyone possibly find out why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to use LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE  ... ?